# Simple definition: query or sub-query?

Tags: sql

I have seen sources saying that an SQL statement such as

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, subject 
FROM student_details 
WHERE games NOT IN ('Cricket', 'Football');
```

is an example of a subquery, but is it not a simple query? I was under the impression that subqueries demand a second call of SELECT, is this correct?

Comment: `('Cricket', 'Football')` is not a subquery. Example of subquery `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE xxx NOT IN (SELECT x FROM table)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A subquery is a query within a query - your example is just a query.

Your source, http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm, is incorrect in some ways, I think.

This is a query that contains a subquery:-

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
SELECT Ord.SalesOrderID, Ord.OrderDate,
    (SELECT MAX(OrdDet.UnitPrice)
     FROM AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS OrdDet
     WHERE Ord.SalesOrderID = OrdDet.SalesOrderID) AS MaxUnitPrice
FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS Ord
```

Answer (score 3):

This statement contains a subquery:

```
Select First_Name, Last_Name, Subject
From Student_Details
Where GameID not in (Select GameID from Games where RequiresHelmet = 1)
```

Yours does not.